# Insert a element as a last element in a list

Tags: c

I'm trying to introduce element after the last position in a list. The result, a list with a point created by the function, but not I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int DATA;

struct lista {

   DATA info;
   struct lista *urm;
};

typedef struct lista Lista,*LISTA;

LISTA newl();
LISTA inserare_in_fata(LISTA l,DATA x);
LISTA inserare_la_sfarsit(LISTA l,DATA x);

int main()
{
   int x;
   FILE *f;
   LISTA l;
   l=newl();
   l=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
   l->urm=NULL;
   scanf("%d",&x);
   l=inserare_in_fata(l,x); //insert a element in front of list
   scanf("%d",&x);
   l=inserare_la_sfarsit(l,x); // the function for insert as last element
   //THE list after Running the program
   printf("\n");
   while(l->urm!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%d->",l->info);
      l=l->urm;
   }
   printf("NULL");

}

LISTA newl()
{
   return NULL;
}

LISTA inserare_la_sfarsit(LISTA l,DATA x)
{
    LISTA w;
    LISTA t=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    t->info=x;
    if(l==NULL)
    {
        l->info=x;
        return l;
    }
    else {
    w=l;
    while(w->urm!=NULL)
    {
        w=w->urm;
    }
    w->urm=t;
    t->urm=NULL;
    return l;
    }
}

LISTA inserare_in_fata(LISTA l,DATA x)
{
    LISTA f;
    f=(LISTA)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    f->info=x;
    if(l==NULL)
    {
        l->info=x;
        return l;
    }
    else{
    f->urm=l;
    return f;
    }
}
```

The number inserted are 30 for the first and 10 for the last which is problem with inserting.

Result : http://uploadimage.ro/1PS0/Sper_ca_e_buna.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a dummy node in the list, with an uninitialized value inside it: After you allocate the memory for `l` in the `main` function`you initialize the "next" member`urm`to`NULL`, but you don't initialize the data member`info`.

The `malloc` function will not initialize the memory it allocates, the data it allocates will have an *indeterminate* value, and using that except to initialize it will lead to *undefined behavior*, which is what happens in your case.

Either initialize the "dummy" node value, or think of another design where you don't need the "dummy" node.

Comment: I updated the question, but after running is the same result.

Comment: @CatalinZambalic You initialize in the wrong place using a condition that won't be true. You need to do it in the `main` function right after you allocate the dummy `l` node.

Comment: I'm using a menu and I use functions for all my menu. This why I use a function to do that.The first element I wanted to be choosed by the user preference, I know that for the first element the functions did the same thing. I put the function with if(l==NULL) in the options for inserare_in_fata and inserare_la_sfarsit for menu and still the same result, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

1. You need

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   ```
2. You don't declare the functions `newl`, `inserare_la_sfarsit`, and `inserare_in_fata` before using them. Add the following declarations

   ```
   LISTA newl();
   LISTA inserare_la_sfarsit(LISTA l,DATA x);
   LISTA inserare_in_fata(LISTA l,DATA x);
   ```

   before `main`.

Comment: I didn't write that also in the question. The functions are already initialized in a library included in project.

Comment: @CatalinZambalic, that's why we like to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It avoids waste of time.